# using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-server

**SharePoint 2013 on-premise**

What is the difference of using:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

with

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

the first code not work, but the second code if it works.

**what is the difference between the second code works and the another not?**

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 on-premise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code wizards, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the first is a lamda which basically states this anonymous function is bound anonymously, but is not instantiated. The second is a delegate that is also instantiated. It's the same as saying:

```
MyHelloDelegateType2 Hello3 = delegate {
 MessageBox.Show("Default message!");
};
```

but you need to instantiate it, it's just creating a delegate object.

```
Hello3("Test");
```

So:

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(Delegate object)` vs `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(Delegated code)`

Comment: ok, the **SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>**  create object anonymous and is executed in other context but the **SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()** needs to be executed in the current context and not allow objects to be anonymous. ok?..

Comment: both are "anonymous". I'm not sure what you are asking; your English is very broken.

Comment: sorry, I know my english is very broken, you answer is correct, thanks! :)